# Flutter Firebase analytics tracking app screen change with Navigator 2.0

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

All examples that I've found are using "navigatorObservers" from the MaterialApp constructor

```
  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
        analytics: analytics,
        observer: observer,
      ),
    );
  }
```

but my app uses MatterialApp.router from the Navigator 2.0 pattern and could not find an equivalent for attaching an navigatorObserver in order to track screen change events for firebase analytics. Any workarounds or suggestions on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`MaterialApp.router`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/MaterialApp.router.html) constructor has required [`routerDelegate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/routerDelegate.html) property. This delegate is usually a wrapper of the `Navigator` widget. This widget has [`observers`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/observers.html) property - that is exactly what you are looking for.

Here is an example of the `RouterDelegate`, which registers both Firebase and Segment observers:

```dart
class AppNavigator extends RouterDelegate<void>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<void> {
  AppNavigator({
    @required Page<void> initialPage,
    this.analyticsObserver,
    this.segmentObserver
  })  : assert(initialPage != null),
        navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>() {
    _pagesStack = [initialPage];
  }

  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver analyticsObserver;
  final SegmentObserver segmentObserver;

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [..._pagesStack],
      observers: [analyticsObserver, segmentObserver],
      onPopPage: (route, dynamic result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
          return false;
        }

        for (final page in _pagesStack) {
          if (page == route.settings) {
            _pagesStack.remove(page);
            notifyListeners();
            break;
          }
        }

        return true;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Note, that under the hood by default the Firebase Analytics module expects your page routes to have a `name` property set as a part of `RouteSettings`:

```
  // From FirebaseAnalyticsObserver
  void _sendScreenView(PageRoute<dynamic> route) {
    final String? screenName = nameExtractor(route.settings);
    if (screenName != null) {
      analytics.setCurrentScreen(screenName: screenName).catchError(
        (Object error) {
          final _onError = this._onError;
          if (_onError == null) {
            debugPrint('$FirebaseAnalyticsObserver: $error');
          } else {
            _onError(error as PlatformException);
          }
        },
        test: (Object error) => error is PlatformException,
      );
    }
  }
```

You can override this behavior by providing custom `nameExtractor` property to the `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` constructor.